# Relation between weak convergence and uniform convergence of integrals

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, lebesgue-integral

Let $f_n$ be a sequence in $L^2(0,1)$ that converges weakly to a function $f \in L^2(0,1)$. Then it is easy to see that the functions

$$F_n(t) := \int_0^t f_n(s) d s$$
converge uniformly to the function
$$F(t) = \int_0^t f(s) d s$$

Sketch of the proof: Clearly $F_n$ pointwise converges to $F$ in $(0,1)$. Using Holder inequality and the fact that since $f_n$ weakly converges, it is bounded in the $L^2$ norm, one finds that there exists a constant $c$ for which it holds

$$\left | F_n(t) -F_n(s) \right|  \leq c \left| t-s\right|^{1/2}, \qquad t, s \in (0,1)$$
Then the conclusion follows from Ascoli Arzelà theorem. (Everything should be the same if we are in a general $L^p$ space).

$\mathbf{ My \; question}$ is: is the condition "$F_n \to F$ uniformly in $(0,1)$" also a sufficient condition for the weak convergence of $f_n$ to $f$? That is, is it true that if $F_n \to F$ uniformly, then for every $\phi \in L^2$ one has
$$\int f_n \phi \to \int f \phi \quad ?$$

If I am not wrong, this holds for every $\phi$ that is a characteristic function of some interval in $(0,1)$, and therefore it holds also for a finite linear combination of them. Then I think one could use some density properties of these functions  to conclude, but I am not sure how to proceed. Thanks to everyone!